# What is the easiest way to find a sql query returns a result or not?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Consider the following sql server query ,

```
 DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Wages FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 20000 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 15000 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 10000
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 45000
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 50000

SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT  *,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Wages DESC) RowID
            FROM    @Table 
        ) sub
WHERE   RowID = 3
```

The result of the query would be `20000` ..... Thats fine as of now i have to find the result of this query,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT  *,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Wages DESC) RowID
            FROM    @Table 
        ) sub
WHERE   RowID = 6
```

It will not give any result because there are only `5` rows in the table.....
so now my question is

What is the easiest way to find a sql query returns a result or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@@ROWCOUNT > 0`

So as a simple example,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT  *,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Wages DESC) RowID
            FROM    @Table 
        ) sub
WHERE   RowID = 6

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 BEGIN
    RETURN 1
END
ELSE BEGIN
    RETURN 0
END
```

For more information, [here's a link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT @@rowcount
```